# How can I achieve fast frame rate of a JPG image display on iOS?

Tags: ios, performance, jpeg, calayer, gpuimage

I've been able to get nearly 10 FPS on iPhone 3GS of solid JPG switching, but I've seen faster is possible with GPU and CALayer.  Can you help me determine how to achieve this?  I’ve tried some various stuff below.

Here’s what I’ve been using…

```
#define FPS 12.0

[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:(1.0 / FPS) target:self selector:@selector(animateMethod:) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
```

Please note the method baseImagePath returns different paths for each invocation.

```
- (void)animateMethod:(NSTimer *)timer
{
    self.imageView.image = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[self baseImagePath]];
}
```

Here’s what I’ve tried…

```
- (void)animateMethod:(NSTimer *)timer
{
    self.layerView.layer.contents = [(__bridge id)([[UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[self baseImagePath]] CGImage]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can approach this from a different angle to achieve the results you want. You can leverage the animation properties of a `UIImageView` to accomplish this. You can preload your images into an array first in the order you want them to show in the animation. Then set up your `UIImageView`.

```
NSMutableArray *images = [NSMutableArray array];
for (int i = 0; i < 16; i++) {
    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed: [NSString stringWithFormat: @"image_%d.jpg", i]];
    [images addObject: image];
}

[self.myImageView setAnimationImages: images];
[self.myImageView setAnimationDuration: 0.5];     // Image view will loop through all images in half a second.
[self.myImageView setAnimationRepeatCount: 0];    // Infinite looping
[self.myImageView startAnimating];
```